# Scifi short-story a planet orbiting a star that switches between visible and ultraviolet light

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story online two or three years ago and have attempted to find it since to no avail.

If I remember correctly, it follows colonists living on a planet that orbits a star that emits extreme amounts of harmful radiation (attributed to deep UV I believe) but is surrounded by a nebula that blocks the harmful UV most/part of the time. When the star is unveiled, strange organisms appear on the surface of the planet — basically a completely separate tree of life only active during those moments.

I remember a specific scene well: several of the characters are outside during one of the moments when the star is unveiled. One of them physically touches a strange ethereal lifeform that has just appeared and is vaporized/consumed instantly.

Any ideas or suggestions to what this could be are appreciated!

Comment: Was it some kind of red dwarf star? How that lifeform looked like? Was it completely online story, or just was available online at that time? How it ended? Who was MC?

Comment: Sounds cool! Seems akin to, but a bit different from, Vernor Vinge's On/Off star.

Answer (score 1):

Larry Niven's *Flare Time* is a possibility, but not a perfect match unless one of us is mis-remembering some details. The main character was a professional tourist, she was shown a lot of the work of the colony and told about the local biology. When the UV light appeared, most animals dived (or burrowed) for cover, and a lot of monsters appeared to hunt the stragglers.

**Parts that match:**

- Human colonists on a planet that suffers bursts of extreme radiation.
- Radiation is said to be (or include) UV, and is harmful to most life on the planet.
- Strange organisms that only appear during radiation bursts, and are effectively separate from the planet's main ecosystem. They're said to evolve rapidly due to the radiation, leading to a plethora of weird forms.
- Characters getting caught out during a burst and being threatened by the odd organisms.

**Part that doesn't match:**

- The radiation is caused by huge solar flares from a normally-red star, not a constant UV star hidden by a nebula.

**Part that might match:**

- That well-remembered scene. I don't remember anyone being vaporised, but the creatures that come out during flares move rapidly and attack anything that moves. There was also a lot of lightning in some areas of the planet - so it's possible in two ways.

Comment: While searching to confirm/deny the above, I came across a comment saying that "JEM", by Frederic Pohl, had a similar theme. Might be worth a look if Flare Time isn't it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I read "JEM", but I remember it as being more about humans from rival political blocs forming alliances with the various intelligent life-forms on Jem and exporting conflicts from Eath to Jem.

Comment: "Flare Time" is part of an anthology: Medea: Harlan's World where all the stories are set on the same planet, so if it's not that particular story, maybe it's another in the same book?